# How to increase the capacity of a stack?

Tags: java, class, stack

I'm using a `Stack` in Java.  The problem is that I only can push 10 items into the stack, and I need to push 20 items.

How do I increment the capacity of the stack?

Comment: Why can you only push ten items?

Comment: This thread is useless without code, please post (if you have any, that is -- I smell shens).

Comment: are you using java.util.Stack, or some other stack of your own creation?

Answer (score 3):

Java's `Stack` class inherits from `Vector` and provides convenience methods to allow a `Vector` to behave like a stack. Since `Vector` grows naturally, there's no need to increase the capacity manually.

I'm guessing you're doing something else wrong. That, or I misunderstood your question. If you want a more accurate answer, please give more information, such as the code your using, what behavior are you expecting, what behavior are you getting, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The Java 7 [Stack](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) is not bound to any size. It is back by a Vector which says it is a "a growable array of objects".

You should be able to add as many object to the Stack as you like.

Answer (score 0):

`Stack` extends `Vector` which has a constructor that defines an initial capacity.
There's also a method called `ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)` which could help you
but as the other posters said: you shouldn't have to do this manually. Maybe providing some code snippets could enlighten us all.