# Difference between Stack.capacity() and Stack.size()

Tags: java, stack

I am currently doing a check with the `Stack<E>` class to see if it's full. However, List does not have a `isFull()` implementation, so I am asking to check if `capacity()` is the same as `size()`. According to the docs, `size()` returns the number of components in this vector, and capacity returns the current capacity of the vector. If I understand correctly, are they the same? And if so, how do I go about checking if my `Stack<E>` is full?

Comment: Define "full"? A Java `Stack` isn't bound to a predetermined size.

Comment: What do *you* mean by "full"? I know what *I'd* mean by full, in terms of the capacity of the underlying array, but without knowing what *you'd* mean by full, we can't really answer.

Comment: Like if it the stack is at max capacity @JonSkeet

Comment: What "max capacity" are you talking about though? Are you expecting a "push" operation to fail?

Comment: There is no defined maximum capacity for a stack. If you want to limit the size of your stack, you will have to check the size yourself. You could implement a derived class, with a `push` operator that does this automatically. But then what: what so you want to do when the stack is full? Throw an exception?

Comment: @JonSkeet yea, exactly. just expecting that

Comment: Well `Stack` doesn't have that kind of capacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Stack` datastructure in Java represents a last-in-first out (LIFO) stack of objects. It extends class `Vector` with five operation such as

1. push
2. pop
3. peek item at the top of the stack
4. Check stack is empty and
5. search for an item in the stack

when the Stack classs would be like as follows

```
public class Stack extends Vector {
}
```

When the stack is created it contains no items. Coming to stack capacity and size

> `Size`     - Number of elements a stack contains at present
>
> `Capacity` - Number of elements it is capable of holding

The `Push` operation is implemented as follows

```
public E push(E item) {
    addElement(item);

    return item;
}
```

`addElement` method belongs to `Vector` class which helps to insert a new element into the `Vector`

```
public synchronized void addElement(E obj) {
    modCount++;
    ensureCapacityHelper(elementCount + 1);
    elementData[elementCount++] = obj;
}
```

`ensureCapacityHelper` allows to check whether the `Vector` inside is capable of adding a new element or not. If it does not have enough space to hold the new element the `Vector` grows

```
 private void ensureCapacityHelper(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    if (minCapacity - elementData.length > 0)
        grow(minCapacity);
}

 /**
 * The maximum size of array to allocate.
 * Some VMs reserve some header words in an array.
 * Attempts to allocate larger arrays may result in
 * OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
 */
private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;

private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + ((capacityIncrement > 0) ?
                                     capacityIncrement : oldCapacity);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}
```

`Arrays.copyOf` is a native method would allocate a new memory space with `newCapacity` and copies the data from old memory location to new location.

Answer (score 3):

`stack.size()` - gives the current size i.e., total number of elements pushed to the stack

`stack.capacity()` - gives the current capacity i.e., array size like 10 or 20 etc... i.e., as soon as you pushes 10 elements to the stack, your stack capacity gets doubled.

Internally `Stack` uses `Vector` and `Vector` is a dynamic growing array. 
Also, for a `Stack`, you can't manually set the `capacityIncrement` factor, rather the stack itself manages internally, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220016/how-to-increase-the-capacity-of-a-stack)

Comment: Capacity usually doubles when a threshold is exceeded. 10, 20, 30 will this not occur. More like 64, 128, 256,....

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius Like `Buddy memory allocation` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation?

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius You can look the answer above added more details

Comment: No, is it dynamic allocation. The vector is stored is one block of sequential memory. This means the **whole** vector needs to be copied when it is reallocated. This can be a costly operation for large vectors.

Comment: _as soon as you pushes 10 elements to the stack, your stack capacity gets doubled_ so how can you overflow a stack? I'm just asking for the sake of understanding this data structure. I'm guessing that **if a stack has a fixed capacity** then it will get overflown if its 'size' becomes more than the 'capacity'. Right? Also it can be overflown if it has a memory capacity as well. Example it has a 'memory' capacity of 100mb but the first 2 items added took all the 100Mb, then the 3rd item will overflow it right?

Answer (score 1):

The `size` is the current number of elements in the stack.

The `capacity` is an internal detail that tells you the maximum items that would fit in the `Vector`.  However, this is not really relevant as it will expand automatically when the capacity is reached.

Comment: No, you are taking to many steps at once. Capacity shows the currently available reserved memory space. Yes it changes "automatically", but it is not irrelevant information. In certain memory limited devices you could require a check, which could indicate you have to free up memory before a vector can increase.

Comment: It is an internal detail, and it is the reason why `ArrayList` no longer exposes this information.

Comment: I donot see how this is relevant to this question.  Can you clarify?

Comment: If you are developing for very memory limited situations, like in low cost embedded devices, you have to manage memory properly. So of you have a vector that has grown a lot in the past (thus has a large capacity) but now only holds a few elements, it might be a good idea and even necessity to resize that vector, to free up memory for other variables. For C++ a `vector::shrink_to_fit`, was introduced to ease this. But it was not introduced until the 2011 standard!

Comment: To be clear, that was sarcasm.  You start with a personal attack there 'guessing' that I never did programming for constrained devices, something which is totally irrelevant for the scope and understanding level of the OP's question.  I wouldn't even touch Java for such work, not that it even existed in the time I was working on such stuff.